# xmlとxslを使ってxmlのデータを五十音順で表示したい

Tags: xml, xsl

xmlとxslを使ってxmlのデータを五十音順で表示する場合どうすればよいでしょうか．
xmlファイルの要素に五十音のにするためのコードを付け加えようと考えているのですがわかりません.
以下コードです.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sample4.xsl"?>
<list>
  <chara category="鳥">
      <name>からす</name>
  </item>
  <chara category="虫">
      <name>あり</name>
  </item>
</list>
```

```xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:template match="list">
<html>
<body>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>名前</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="chara">
    <xsl:sort select="chara" data-type="text" order="ascending" />
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 最初のＸＭＬがおかしいと思いますが・

Answer (score 3, accepted):

質問のxmlとxslには問題点があります。以下の原則を意識して見直してみてください。

xmlは原則として<開始タグ>を開始タグと同名の</終了タグ>で閉じる必要があります。
末尾に"/"のある<空要素タグ/>は閉じる必要がありませんが、開始タグと混同しないよう注意が必要です。

この原則をふまえて質問にあるxmlを見直すと、<chara>が</chara>で閉じられていないことが分かります。
xslも同様に以下のタグが閉じられていません。

- <xsl:stylesheet>
- <xsl:template>
- <xsl:for-each>

</item>を</chara>に直したxmlの例は以下のようになります。

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sample4.xsl"?>
<list>
  <chara category="鳥">
      <name>からす</name>
      <name>いぬ</name>
      <name>ごりら</name>
  </chara>
  <chara category="虫">
      <name>あり</name>
      <name>きりぎりす</name>
  </chara>
</list>
```

全カテゴリーをまとめてソートしたい場合は、以下を参考にsample4.xslを直してみてください。

```html
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" />
        <xsl:template match="list" >
        <html>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>種類</th>
                        <th>名前</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="chara/name">
                        <xsl:sort select="." data-type="text" order="ascending" />
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="../@category" /></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

カテゴリーごとにソートしたい場合は、以下を参考にsample4.xslを直してみてください。

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:template match="list" >
<html>
<body>
    <ul>
    <xsl:for-each select="chara">
        <li><xsl:value-of select="./@category" /></li>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>名前</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="name">
                <xsl:sort select="." data-type="text" order="ascending" />
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```